# How to enable plymouth on Fedora 20 and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

this is my very first tryout with Fedora (I'm a long time ubuntu user).
I successfully installed F20 + Guest Additions on VirtualBox 4.3. Everything works well except for a "cosmetic" thing: the boot animation is in text mode only (the three srtipes on the bottom). Is there a way to enable graphical boot animation (plymouth)?
I've read that plymouth requires kms, so I'm wondering if that is avaiable on VirtualBox.
Besides fixing this cosmetic thing, I'm posting this question in order to learn more about F20, plymouth and kms.
Thanks in advance!